# Spark Map a DataSet with a function that generates other dataset and save in a new Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm starting to work with Scala and Spark. Currently, I consume a Rest service and with the response I generate a Dataset from the JSON, with the following structure:

```
|   id   |     name       |        key          |
+------- + -------------- + ------------------- +
| 128b16 | sample_project | uk.uda.proyect: ... |
```

From this DataSet, I need to go through its rows and for each "key" element consume another Rest service (one call per row) and save the response of all rows in a new data set, for example, like this:

```
|   key  | value_1|value_2|value_n ... |
+ ------ + -------+------ + ---------- +
| 128b16 | xxxxxx |  xxxx | xxxx       |
```

Any idea how I could achieve this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are saving the JSON responses into the database, you could write a producer script for a messaging queue like Kafka or RabbitMQ.

You could then create a spark streaming job to consume that message, the message can be just the "key" value or the whole dataset from the JSON response. You can can save these results into any database you want, either RDMBS or NOSQL databases. There are really good connectors available to make the job really simple.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, currently I don't persist the data in a database, I obtain the first response and save in a DataSet and with this I need to consume the other Rest services n times (one per key-row).

Comment: You do not have to save it in a database, you can send that message without saving it through a messaging queue. Every time the message is triggered, the consumer, which in this case is spark streaming calls the secondary rest service from the consumed message. This can be a call per row or for whole message.